# Accessing Android Sensors with C/C++ Application

Tags: android, c++, c, android-sensors

Is there a way to access the android sensors( x,y, z data ) with a c/c++ application.As I understand there is way to access it only though the JNI which is a interface between android app and the framework.
I read and tried to build the native app(from the android-ndk-r10d\samples\native-activity)  as an executable .My Android.mk looks like :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := native-activity
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv1_CM
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

I have changed the android_main to main() in the native-activity\jni\main.c file.But after i pushed it to android file system and ran ./native-activity i got this error : 
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE : could not load library "libandroid.so" needed by

```
`./native-activity:cause by "libandroid.so" has unexpected e_machine: 3`
```

I have moved the libandroid.so from the system/lib/ to the current directory of the native-activity.

What is wrong I am doing?Is there any other better way to access the android sensors data with c/c++ application  ?

Comment: Most Android IPC services are actually implemented in Java, and so even when using a "native activity" end up running glue code for the IPC API's in a Dalvik or Android Runtime engine included in the process.  Your pure native executable lacks this, and so has no official way to talk to those resources.  Why are you trying to run a pure native program?  There is no *normal* way to invoke such on an Android device in a production setting anyway - yes, you *can* launch it from an Activity or Service, but what is the perceived benefit?

Comment: That said, your actually error arrises from trying to link a library built for a different architecture than you are compiling for.  It still won't work (with massive behind the scenes hackery) even if you get past that, but the fact that you are getting this error suggests you've already been manually copying system components between directories without a clear understanding of how they relate.